# how to check digit is even or not in linux shell? 

Tags: linux

i tried

```
pancmite@atlas:~$ test ($LSD / 2) -eq 0
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$LSD'

pancmite@atlas:~$ test $LSD / 2 -eq 0
bash: test: too many arguments

pancmite@atlas:~$ test $number -lt $LSD
bash: test: -lt: unary operator expected
```

i want one line command.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr $LSD % 2
```

or alternatively:

```
$((LSD % 2))
```

A returned value of 1 is odd and 0 is even. So you could try this as a test:

```
LSD=5
echo $((LSD % 2))
```

and you should get a returned value of 1.

Comment: @Terminator Don't forget to accept the answer. There's an outline of a check mark near the answer.